# pdo fetchAll in a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have a foreach with categories id's and then in that foreach i query database foreach id category. How can i return result of all fetched products? Here is my query

```
function produse_by_categ($id)
    {

        $stmt=$this->db->prepare("Select id_category FROM tbl_catalog_categories where name=:id");
        $stmt->bindParam(":id",$id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        foreach ($result as $categ)
        {
            $stmtt=$this->db->prepare("Select id_category FROM tbl_catalog_categories where id_parent=:id");
            $stmtt->bindParam(":id",$categ['id_category']);
            $stmtt->execute();
            $resultt = $stmtt->fetchAll();

            $stmtt=$this->db->prepare("Select * FROM tbl_products
                                INNER JOIN tbl_products_to_categories on tbl_products_to_categories.id_category=:id 
                                and tbl_products_to_categories.id_product=tbl_products.id_product ");
            $stmtt->bindParam(":id",$categ['id_category']);
            $stmtt->execute();
            $resulttt = $stmtt->fetchAll();

            return $resulttt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `where name= id` ? are your sure?

Comment: yes, actualy id is the name of the category from the url like 'books'

Comment: so basically if id is books you are actually saying `SELECT id_category FROM tbl_catalog_categories where name='books'` ?

Comment: so whats not working on your current code? what are you not getting?

Comment: yep, and then on the foreach i have the id's of the categories that are parent to the main category, and i want to select all products that have id_category from the foreach. for example my id categories for books are 131 132 133 134 135

Comment: then why so many queries, I think u can achieve this with one query, using joins? did u tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use joins to combine all 3 queries into one, do not re-do joins in php code.

```
Select *
FROM tbl_products p
INNER JOIN tbl_products_to_categories ptoc on ptoc.id_product=tbl_products.id_product
INNER JOIN tbl_catalog_categories c1 on ptoc.id_category=c1.id_category
INNER JOIN tbl_catalog_categories c2 on c1.id_parent=c2.id_category
WHERE c2.name=:id
```

This way you can avoid the multiple nested loops within php that are basically simulating the joins. The `:id` parameter in the above query is the `$id` parameter supplied to the php function. Just loop through the results of the above query to get all products belonging to all the categories.

If a product belongs to multiple categories, then the above query (similarly to your own code) will list it multiple times.

Comment: thnx a lot, this is exactly what i was looking for, how to simulate joins instead doing multiple loops. It's working thnx again!

Comment: Just to clarify: your code is simulating joins, my answer actually contains the joins :)

Comment: and if i have another lvl of subsubmenu i'll add another join like this right?`INNER JOIN tbl_catalog_categories c3 on c2.id_parent=c3.id_category`

Comment: It depends. You probably need a left join in this case, and if you have even more subcategories, then you are facing an even more complex problem.

Comment: i only have 3 lvls category->subcategory->subsubcategory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136965/discussion-between-user3463807-and-shadow).